# injecting javascript in my html

Tags: javascript, html, security, http

Very frequently I find in the logs requests for javascript that are not part of my website.

One such javascript is "showpass-1.5.js" and error looks like:

```
2015/12/06 07:03:27 [error] 14129#0: *54208136 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/nsl.mapticket.net/sd/apps/showpass/showpass-1.5.js" failed (2: No such file or directory) [...]
```

I'm thinking that someone injects arbitrary code into the html of my website and tries to collect information about my users. But who and in what circumstances?

I don't have a lot of experience with HTTP protocols. Is this a vulnerability of the sites using HTTP (so not HTTPS) and how one can protect his website from this types of activities?

Comment: ns1.mapticket.net is adware/malware that is installed on a client's machine, it adds like bho,plugins, etc into a clients browser to display ad's, nothing you can do as its a client's own issue not a site issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those requests are coming from the ShowPass adware script - as the above commenter noted, it's most likely a matter of your visitors' machines being infected, rather than your site. There's not much you can do about it, but it isn't a direct threat to your site or server.

For more details:
http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/ShowPass-Smartbar-132262-program.aspx